# If else if statement for variable to another variable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need to have a Google Form that returns the result of variable2 depends on the result of variable1. The code runs successfully but the variable 2 does not change.

No matter what the value of BranchChoices is, the result will always be LN2. Did I missed out anything?

```
   item = "Branch"; 
   var bN2 =  ["A", "B", "C"]
   var bN1 = ["1", "2"]
   var bN3 = ["1", "2", "A", "B", "C"]
   var BranchChoices = bN3;  
   form.addMultipleChoiceItem()  
       .setTitle(item)  
       .setChoiceValues(BranchChoices)  
       .setRequired(true); 
 
   item = "Location";   
   var LN1 = ["I"];  
   var LN2 = ["P"]; 
   var LN3 = ["I:", "P:"]; 
   
   if(BranchChoices = bN2) {
     var LocationChoices = LN2;
     } else if (BranchChoices = bN1) {
     var LocationChoices = LN1 ;
     } else if (BranchChoices = bN3) {
     var LocationChoices = LN3 ;
     }

   form.addMultipleChoiceItem()  
       .setTitle(item)  
       .setChoiceValues(LocationChoices)  
       .setRequired(true);
```

Comment: Apart from the issue of mixing up assignment and comparison operators (see Cooper's answer) it looks like you want to compare two arrays. You cannot do it simply with a comparison operator. How do you want to compare the arrays? (1) Check whether they have the same elements? (2) Same elements in same order? (3) Or maybe just that all elements in one array are also in the other? Please consider clarifying this. Also, based on the code you provided, `BranchChoices` will always be the same as `bN3`, so what's the point of the `if...else` blocks?

Answer (score 0):

#### The difference between assignment and conditional

This is an assignment `if(BranchChoices = bN2) {`

This is probably what you really want `if(BranchChoices == bN2) {`

You made the same error in several places fix them all.  There may be other errors.  You code is incomplete.